# How to convert a synchronous view to async view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-asyncio

I'm working on a django view to get list of available riders. I first created in a synchronous context and when I tested it, it worked as expected. I need it to be in an asynchronous context, but when I tried to convert i to an async context, I get this error message below:

```
   raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Here's the code in an async context I came up with trying to convert to an async context, but got the error above:

```
riderexpert_db = firestore.AsyncClient(project="riderexpert", database="riderexpert-db")

class GetAvailableRidersView(APIView): 
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 
    SEARCH_RADIUS_METERS = 10
    async def get_google_maps_client(self):
        """Initialize and return the asynchronous Google Maps API client."""
        return GoogleMapsClient(key=settings.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)

    async def validate_parameters(self, order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile):
        """Validate input parameters."""
        try:
            item_capacity = float(item_capacity)
            is_fragile = str_to_bool(is_fragile)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return False, "Invalid or missing parameters"

        if not all(
            [
                order_location is not None and isinstance(order_location, str),
                item_capacity is not None and isinstance(item_capacity, (int, float)),
                is_fragile is not None and isinstance(is_fragile, bool),
            ]
        ):
            return False, "Invalid or missing parameters"
        return True, ""

    def handle_google_maps_api_error(self, e):
        """Handle Google Maps API errors."""
        return Response(
            {"status": "error", "message": f"Google Maps API error: {str(e)}"},
            status=400,
        )

    def handle_internal_error(self, e):
        """Handle internal server errors."""
        logger.error(str(e))
        return Response(
            {"status": "error", "message": "Error processing the request"}, status=500
        )

    async def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order_location = request.GET.get("origin")
        item_capacity = request.GET.get("item_capacity")
        is_fragile = request.GET.get("is_fragile")

        # Handle Missing or Invalid Parameters
        is_valid, validation_message = await self.validate_parameters(
            order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile
        )
        if not is_valid:
            return Response(
                {"status": "error", "message": validation_message}, status=400
            )

        try:
            # Initialize asynchronous Google Maps API client
            gmaps = await self.get_google_maps_client()

            # Optimize Database Queries
            available_riders = await self.get_available_riders(
                gmaps, order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile
            )

            return Response({"status": "success", "riders": available_riders})
        except ApiError as e:
            logger.error(f"Google Maps API error: {str(e)}")
            return self.handle_google_maps_api_error(e)
        except Exception as e:
            return self.handle_internal_error(e)
        finally:
            # Close the asynchronous Firestore client
            await riderexpert_db.close()

    async def get_available_riders(self, gmaps, order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile):
        try:
            # Query asynchronous Firestore for available riders locations
            riders_collection = await riderexpert_db.collection("riders").stream()

            riders_within_radius = []
            for firestore_rider in riders_collection:
                firestore_data = firestore_rider.to_dict()

                # Retrieve rider from Django model using email as identifier
                email = firestore_data.get("email")

                # Construct queryset to filter riders based on conditions
                queryset = Rider.objects.filter(
                    user__email=email,
                    is_available=True,
                    fragile_item_allowed=is_fragile,
                    min_capacity__lte=item_capacity,
                    max_capacity__gte=item_capacity,
                )
                # Check if the queryset is not empty
                if queryset.exists():
                    django_rider = queryset.first()
                    rider_location = (
                        firestore_data.get("current_latitude"),
                        firestore_data.get("current_longitude"),
                    )

                    distance_matrix_result = await gmaps.distance_matrix(
                        origins=order_location,
                        destinations=rider_location,
                        mode="driving",
                        units="metric",
                    )

                    distance = distance_matrix_result["rows"][0]["elements"][0][
                        "distance"
                    ]
                    duration = distance_matrix_result["rows"][0]["elements"][0][
                        "duration"
                    ]["text"]

                    if distance["value"] <= self.SEARCH_RADIUS_METERS * 1000:
                        # Include both distance and duration in the response
                        rider_data = {
                            "rider": RiderSerializer(django_rider).data,
                            "distance": distance,
                            "duration": duration,
                        }
                        riders_within_radius.append(rider_data)

            return riders_within_radius

        except ApiError as e:
            return self.handle_google_maps_api_error(e)`
```

So I modified it using the `sync_to_async from asgiref.sync`  as shown below:

```
riderexpert_db = firestore.AsyncClient(project="riderexpert", database="riderexpert-db")


class GetAvailableRidersView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    SEARCH_RADIUS_METERS = 10

    async def get_google_maps_client(self):
        """Initialize and return the asynchronous Google Maps API client."""
        return GoogleMapsClient(key=settings.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)

    async def validate_parameters(self, order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile):
        """Validate input parameters."""
        try:
            item_capacity = float(item_capacity)
            is_fragile = str_to_bool(is_fragile)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return False, "Invalid or missing parameters"

        if not all(
            [
                order_location is not None and isinstance(order_location, str),
                item_capacity is not None and isinstance(item_capacity, (int, float)),
                is_fragile is not None and isinstance(is_fragile, bool),
            ]
        ):
            return False, "Invalid or missing parameters"
        return True, ""

    def handle_google_maps_api_error(self, e):
        """Handle Google Maps API errors."""
        return Response(
            {"status": "error", "message": f"Google Maps API error: {str(e)}"},
            status=400,
        )

    def handle_internal_error(self, e):
        """Handle internal server errors."""
        logger.error(str(e))
        return Response(
            {"status": "error", "message": "Error processing the request"}, status=500
        )

    async def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order_location = request.GET.get("origin")
        item_capacity = request.GET.get("item_capacity")
        is_fragile = request.GET.get("is_fragile")

        # Handle Missing or Invalid Parameters
        is_valid, validation_message = await self.validate_parameters(
            order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile
        )
        if not is_valid:
            return Response(
                {"status": "error", "message": validation_message}, status=400
            )

        try:
            # Initialize asynchronous Google Maps API client
            gmaps = await self.get_google_maps_client()

            # Optimize Database Queries
            available_riders = await self.get_available_riders(
                gmaps, order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile
            )

            return Response({"status": "success", "riders": available_riders})
        except ApiError as e:
            logger.error(f"Google Maps API error: {str(e)}")
            return self.handle_google_maps_api_error(e)
        except Exception as e:
            return self.handle_internal_error(e)
        finally:
            # Close the Firestore client
            await riderexpert_db.close()

    async def get_available_riders(self, gmaps, order_location, item_capacity, is_fragile):
        try:
            # Use sync_to_async for Firestore operations
            riders_collection = await sync_to_async(
                riderexpert_db.collection("riders").stream
            )()

            riders_within_radius = []
            for firestore_rider in riders_collection:
                firestore_data = firestore_rider.to_dict()

                # Retrieve rider from Django model using email as identifier
                email = firestore_data.get("email")

                # Construct queryset to filter riders based on conditions
                queryset = Rider.objects.filter(
                    user__email=email,
                    is_available=True,
                    fragile_item_allowed=is_fragile,
                    min_capacity__lte=item_capacity,
                    max_capacity__gte=item_capacity,
                )
                # Check if the queryset is not empty
                if queryset.exists():
                    django_rider = queryset.first()
                    rider_location = (
                        firestore_data.get("current_latitude"),
                        firestore_data.get("current_longitude"),
                    )

                    distance_matrix_result = await gmaps.distance_matrix(
                        origins=order_location,
                        destinations=rider_location,
                        mode="driving",
                        units="metric",
                    )

                    distance = distance_matrix_result["rows"][0]["elements"][0][
                        "distance"
                    ]
                    duration = distance_matrix_result["rows"][0]["elements"][0][
                        "duration"
                    ]["text"]

                    if distance["value"] <= self.SEARCH_RADIUS_METERS * 1000:
                        # Include both distance and duration in the response
                        rider_data = {
                            "rider": RiderSerializer(django_rider).data,
                            "distance": distance,
                            "duration": duration,
                        }
                        riders_within_radius.append(rider_data)

            return riders_within_radius

        except ApiError as e:
            return self.handle_google_maps_api_error(e)
```

But I still get this error instead:

```
result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs) 
TypeError: object Response can't be used in 'await' expression
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: that's 100+ lines of code. Can you show the whole traceback where are you getting this error?

Comment: If you're not using `await` anywhere in a function, then there's no point in using async functions.

Answer (score 0):

When your are using orm functionality of django in async context you can have two options (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/):

1. wrap orm methods calls in sync_to_async
2. call async queryset method variant (for example aget, aexist, acount and etc.) and await it.

In your code I see here several example where you call orm in async functions which can lead to the error you are receiving:

```
queryset = Rider.objects.filter(
   user__email=email,
   is_available=True,
   fragile_item_allowed=is_fragile,
   min_capacity__lte=item_capacity,
   max_capacity__gte=item_capacity,
)
# Check if the queryset is not empty
if queryset.exists():
   django_rider = queryset.first()
   rider_location = (
      firestore_data.get("current_latitude"),
      firestore_data.get("current_longitude"),
   )
```

this for sure will lead to error because you call orm sync methods in async function. The correct way is:

```
queryset = Rider.objects.filter(
   user__email=email,
   is_available=True,
   fragile_item_allowed=is_fragile,
   min_capacity__lte=item_capacity,
   max_capacity__gte=item_capacity,
)
# Check if the queryset is not empty
if await queryset.aexists():
   django_rider = await queryset.afirst()
   rider_location = (
      # if firestore_data is queryset
      await firestore_data.aget("current_latitude"),
      await firestore_data.aget("current_longitude"),
   )
```

It's just one example where you can get this error, you should correct all your orm methods calls in code provided by you.